# Is there a way to have grid automatically align items based on their content?

Tags: css, css-grid

What I mean is depending on the content of each item it decides if the item should take up 2 spaces in a column. Imagine a notice board where people post notes of different lengths and they should pop up next to each other without empty spaces. If there is a long note next to a short note the next note would show up next to the long one but under the short one.

Comment: is masonry what you are looking for?

Comment: no there is not

Comment: If you want a Pinterest board type layout, CSS Grid by itself can't do this yet although like @RamondeVries said there is a masonry spec for Grid but it's not live in browsers yet. You would need JavaScript to accomplish this.